# Using SSH tunnel with jOOQ

Tags: gradle, jooq, ssh-tunnel

I'm configuring jOOQ via Gradle in my project and need to start connecting to my database via an SSH tunnel. I can't find any documentation on how to get started. My current configuration (without the tunnel) looks like:

```
task generateJooq << {
    def writer = new StringWriter()
    new MarkupBuilder(writer).configuration('xmlns': 'http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.9.0.xsd') {
        jdbc() {
            driver('org.postgresql.Driver')
            url(props.getProperty('datasource.url')) // From a properties file
            user(props.getProperty('datasource.user')) // From a properties file
            password(props.getProperty('datasource.pass')) // From a properties file
        }
        generator() {
            database() {
                inputSchema('public')
            }
            generate() {
                pojos(true)
                daos(true)
            }
            target() {
                packageName('com.foo.bar.model.dao')
                directory(Paths.get(project.projectDir.toString(), 'src/main/java'))
            }
        }
    }

    GenerationTool.generate(
            JAXB.unmarshal(new StringReader(writer.toString()), org.jooq.util.jaxb.Configuration.class)
    )
}
```

How would I modify this configuration to use an SSH tunnel to connect to my database?

Comment: What problem are you experiencing?

Comment: @LukasEder, I know how to tell jOOQ to connect to a database directly, but I don't know how to set it up to use an SSH tunnel. So I'm looking for a configuration that would connect to a database by using a proxy/SSH tunnel server.

Answer (score 0):

jOOQ's code generator configuration doesn't offer a lot of stuff on top of what JDBC already offers out of the box. So the standard approach is to provide a JDBC url, username, password, and optionally, some properties.

If you already have a JDBC `Connection` (which you constructed through an SSH tunnel, depending on what you mean by that), you can also pass that to the `GenerationTool`. Replace your `GenerationTool` call by this:

```java
GenerationTool tool = new GenerationTool();
tool.setConnection(connection);
tool.generate(configuration); // Your JAXB call here...
```